# How do I run tests remotely with VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015

I've got some CodedUI tests I'd like to run on a remote machine from visual studio. Now it used to be that you'd install a test controller somewhere, a test agent on the box you want to run on, get them talking, then use a test settings file that was pointed to that controller. I was going through this and installed agents for 2015 update 3 on my run box. I noticed that there is no controller configuration option. After some googling I found this: https://vstfsalm.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/tfs-2015-test-agent-has-not-been-configured-run-the-test-agent-configuration-tool-to-configure-the-test-agent/. Very cool. So I go in to tfs to set up a machine group. Great. The part I don't get is: how can I now tell VS to run at that group? Test settings files require a controller when they are set to remote run. Do I have to downgrade the agents back to 2013? Does anyone know if Microsoft just didn't implement this work style in 2015 (on purpose or otherwise) or if it just isn't implemented yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the code UI test via vNext build on TFS update3. First make sure the code UI test can be executed successfully in your Visual Studio on your remote machine locally.  Also don't forget to configure the build agent to **interact** with desktop.

Then you just need to add **Deploy TestAgent on RemoteTestMachine** task and run Functional test. When you queue a build, it will deploy your code ui test solution to the drop folder on the build server machine. Then use MSTEST to run the test assembly. It's same with running code UI test via MSTEST command line on your local machine.

[image]

---

**Update**

> Q: Will the Test Agent 2015 support all the scenarios supported by
>   Test Controller and Test Agent of Visual Studio 2013?

A: We recommend you use Agents for Visual Studio 2015 in all the new automated testing scenarios. You can use the Deploy Test Agents task in a build definition to download and install the test agents on your machine. The following table shows the scenarios supported by Agents for Visual Studio 2013 and the alternatives for Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 and Team Services (TS).

[image]

Source Link: [Install and configure test agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)

**Currently, there is no alternative for this scenarion.** You may have to use test agent 2013 to achieve it.

Comment: The important bit was from VS, not from a build. I don't want to run it with a build. That would require a check-in. I want to run the code I have that is just on my box through a test agent on a remote server and it looks like I no longer can.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there is no alternative  for this scenarion. You may have to use test agent 2013 to achieve it. More details please see my update answer.