# Can I run a load test created with VS2015 over 2013 controllers from TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have built a load test for a web application configured to run on a separate controller and test agents. This is a data driven load test.

My controller and agents are all 2013. Visual Studio is able to recognize the controller and agents.

When I try to run the test remotely, I receive the error: "Failed to queue test run 'myusername@mymachinename datetimestamp': No such host is known. The agent for the run is given as my machine - which I have not set up as a controller or agent for remote runs.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031381/how-do-i-run-tests-remotely-with-vs2015) what I am trying to do is not possible with VS2015. I cannot run the tests against production, and my test subnet can't be accessed from outside the company intranet.

Our in-house Team Foundation Server is running TFS2012.

**Is it possible to use TFS2012 to manage VS2013 controller and agent machines to run a load test created in VS2015?**

I've spent days looking for a way around this problem, and come up with no answers.

Comment: Do you need to use TFS for these tests? You can run load tests from Visual Studio and (as far as I know) VS2015 test can use A&C2013.

Comment: Not to run remotely it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of extra research, I've come to the conclusion that the answer is:

**No**

Visual Studio and TFS version dependencies for build and test are sufficiently tightly integrated that trying to work across three separate versions would require more effort than the outcome is worth even if there is no functionality in the load tests that is not available with the 2013 or 2012 DLLs.

Answering this so that anyone else who needs to know can use the solution.

In my case the solution is to build an instance of TFS2015 and begin working with it to run testing, with the existing 2012 work to be migrated across over time.