# Visual studio test task configuration with single build agent and multiple test machines

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, azure-devops

Lately two tasks became deprecated in vsts: Deploy TestAgent and Run Functional Tests.
Both allowed to specify list of machines where tests would be run and use single build agent. 
Now there is Visual Studio Test instead and I am trying to find a solution to keep tests being distributed to multiple test machines with single build agent.
Related tests are ui based.

Browsing msdn blogs contain some suggestions but so far did not helped me to find consistent solution.

Please help?

Links that I tried:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/26/vstest-task-dons-a-new-avatar-testing-with-unified-agents-and-phases/

[How do I run tests remotely with VS2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031381/how-do-i-run-tests-remotely-with-vs2015)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1410

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/21/remote-testing-distributing-tests-based-on-number-of-machines/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/05/29/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/allendm/2015/07/20/remote-test-execution-using-team-foundation-server-2015-rc2-and-beyond/

Comment: Why not add links to some of the solutions you have already tried out from MSDN blogs (& other places)? That way people will not give you answers that won't work for you.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/26/vstest-task-dons-a-new-avatar-testing-with-unified-agents-and-phases/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031381/how-do-i-run-tests-remotely-with-vs2015

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1410

Comment: Add this link in the main body of the question: people may not notice it here.

Comment: @markvgti Links to what he tried will get this question closed faster than it already will. What he's tried is to be posted here within his question. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to register multiple build agent in these machines (Deployment Groups uses the build agent too and can use in Deployment group phase)

With single build agent, you can use old way even though the tasks are deprecated, you may refer to the source code of [DeployVisualStudioTestAgent and RunDistributedTests](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) to build a custom task extension.

Comment: Thank you starian, custom task extension seems interesting.
Can I expect deprecated tasks to be available in the future?

Comment: I think we'd expect the better way in future.

Answer (score 0):

Like starian chen said, the two tasks have been replaced but you can accomplish nearly all of the same functionality with the new tasks.  Having the unified agent to handle builds, releases, and test execution does simplify some challenges of deprecated tasks such as copying the files and getting the build agent to communicate via WinRM.  I just wrote a blog post on this.  My next post will cover scaling out multiple machines and doing cross browser testing like you are asking about.
http://www.deliveron.com/blog/configuring-ui-test-agents-using-visual-studio-test-task-vsts/

Is there any reason you can't install a build agent on each of your test agent VMs?  Be sure to put them into their own Agent Queue/Pool.